# Visual tool for browsing LMDB files

Tags: windows

I am looking for a Windows program that can open and display an LMDB file ([Lightning Memory-Mapped Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database)). Ideally, gratis, can also edit the file, and supports large files, like [HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/) for HDF4 and HDF5 files.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can try [FastoNoSQL](https://fastonosql.com) gui manager for lmdb databases.[image: ][1]]]

Answer (score 1):

I would say it would be worth taking a look at [python](http://python.org) & [ipython](http://ipython.org/) + [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) & the [LMDB](https://github.com/dw/py-lmdb/) bindings for python.

- Interactive browsing of LMDB, *and just about any other DB*.
- Pandas can display and manipulate HDRF5 files - *you may need to add the [HDRF4](https://github.com/fhs/python-hdf4) library*.
- **Free** - both gratis & open source
- Cross platform - *even Windows*

### Additional Examples & Information

- [Simple Interactive Data Analysis with Python](http://pbpython.com/simple-data-analysis.html) walks you thoroug getting started.
- A simple starter [example](http://pbpython.com/simple-graphing-pandas.html) for Business Use
- A gallery of ["Interesting" iPython Notebooks](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/A-gallery-of-interesting-IPython-Notebooks) that provides a categorised set of very impressive notebooks.
- I can also recommend the O'Reilly book Python for Data Analysis ISBN-10: 1449319793 ISBN-13: 978-1449319793

Comment: Not really a GUI though.

Comment: I thought the question was Visual Tool not a GUI

Comment: "Windows program that can open and display an LMDB file" in the graphical manner demonstrated. How do you get that functionality with ipython + pandas?

Comment: @empty - you start an iPython notebook on Windows, import pandas, read the file and you can display values, columns, graphs of values, etc., edit values select subsets etc and save to the same or a different file. If you would like you can even have sliders to select the range(s) of displayed values.

Comment: thanks!  Is there a link that you could recommend that would give me the basic idea how to do this?  I've looked but not found anything promising.

Comment: http://pbpython.com/simple-graphing-pandas.html gives a good example and I will add a link or two to the answer.

Comment: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/joyofdata/joyofdata-articles/blob/master/deeplearning-with-caffe/Neural-Networks-with-Caffe-on-the-GPU.ipynb is also worth a look.